# Ansible: Polling a log file for idle time before server restart

Tags: ansible

I'd like Ansible to tail a log file and wait for idle time - say for example XX seconds where the logs are idle for that time.

If the logs are not idle within that XX seconds, continue to wait until we have XX seconds of idle time.

If the idle time elapses then Ansible will restart the server.

Idle time can be calculated by checking the last 2 log entries and the time difference between them.

How can I go about achieving this with Ansible?

Comment: It doesn't make sense to apply a patchwork of Ansible modules to achieve this (and there is no ready-made one and probably never will). You can write a script in any language and call it from a playbook.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There's no need to wait for two log entries XX seconds apart rather than just waiting until XX seconds after the last log entry since if you've gone longer than XX seconds the next write will match your condition.

And on that basis, just do this (for example purposes XX = 5)

```
- find: paths="/tmp" patterns="logfile" age="5s" age_stamp="mtime"
  register: modified
  until: modified.matched == 1
  retries: 20
  delay: 5
```

Just make sure the paths and patterns specifications match only your log file.

Comment: This solution worked for our requirement. Thanks for your help!

Comment: @O.Elhelou glad to hear it, thanks for the feedback.

Answer (score 1):

If you have a command to print the time difference in seconds, you can use:

```
- shell: /opt/myscripts/log_difference.sh
  register: result
  until: result.stdout | int > 60
  retries: 5
  delay: 10
```

This will execute log_difference.sh until number of retries is exceeded or number in stdout is greater than 60.